# ASP NET regresar un vista

Tags: sql, asp.net, cshtml

Amigos quiero regresar un ruta en especifico de mi proyecto, después de hacer un insert, pero me da el siguiente error

> No se encuentra ninguna ruta con el nombre '/ProductoFinanciero/Details/1' en la colección de rutas.
>   Nombre del parámetro: name

[image: error]

este es mi código

```
  [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult InsertInteres(string id_user, string interes, int id_producto,string name)
    {

        using (DBEnt db = new DBEnt())
        {

            DateTime aDate = DateTime.Now;
            var interestr = interes;
            interestr = interestr.Replace("%", "");

            var intereDeci = Convert.ToDecimal(interestr);
            var interx = new ProductoFinancieroInteres()
            {
                id_productofinanciero = id_producto,
                interes = intereDeci
            };

            db.ProductoFinancieroInteres.Add(interx);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        var action = "Insert";
        var comments = "Interes para Producto Financiero "+name+" ingresado por el usuario : ";
        InsertInBitacora(id_user, action, comments + id_user);

        return RedirectToRoute("/ProductoFinanciero/Details/"+ id_producto);

    }
```

Comment: Dudo mucho que tengas un objeto (página) para cada uno de los productos. Seguramente necesitas una página que reciba un parámetro del id_producto. No creo que haya suficiente información para una solución completa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método `RedirectToRoute("NombreRuta")`, redirige en función al **Nombre de la Ruta** que hayas indicado en el archivo de configuración `RouteConfig.cs` (si estas utilizando ASP.NET MVC).

Por ejemplo si indicas `RedirectToRoute("Default")` estarás haciendo referencia a la ruta definida en el `RouteConfig.cs` con el nombre "**Default**":

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

En tu caso debes utilizar el método `RedirectToAction()` indicando la **Acción**, el **Controlador** y el **parámetro** de la siguiente forma:

```
return RedirectToAction("Details", "ProductoFinanciero", new { id = id_producto });
```